# Dynamically Pass Component props in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a component Form like below -

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps, getReqCookie }) => {
  const variable = Component.variable;
  console.log(variable)
}
```

```
const Index = () => {

}
Index.variable = "something"
```

Currently passing static variable to MyApp like this. But how can I pass this variable dynamically to my MyApp?

the variable should load API data and pass it to MyApp Component.

Example:

```
Index.variable = {fetched data from api}
```

I used getserverSideprops and initialize the data inside it. But not working.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const data = fetched from API
  Index.variable = data;
}
```

Comment: _"the variable should load API data and pass it to MyApp Component."_ - That's what [Next.js data fetching methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/index) are used for. Have you tried using `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: I used getserversideprops but didn't work as expected. getstaticprops is not acceptable in this scenario. cause I don't want build time to create.

Comment: Did you check the [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) documentation? That's not how you return data from it.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I asked I have some data on the page successfully fetched from getServerSideProps. Now I want to register those data in Index.variable and send it to MyApp Component .

Comment: What I mean is that you don't need to pass the data that way. Data returned from `getServerSideProps` is available in the [custom `_app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) by accessing the `pageProps` prop. Return the data from `getServerSideProps` like the example and it'll be available.

Comment: thank's it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Next.js doesn't provide mechanism for attaching "dynamic data" to components. Probably because this approach presents several problems to solve. What data exactly should be fetched? When? By what component? One of the workarounds would be to attach data fetching function to the page:

```
Page.fetchData = async () => {
  // fetch data from api
}
```

And then resolving it in _app.js:

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    Component.fetchData().then((resolvedData) => {
      setFetchedData(resolvedData);
    });
  }, [Component]);

  // do something with fetchedData
};
```

On the other hand, did you consider just fetching this data inside page and pass it to components down the tree?

Comment: I liked the workaround. But I found @juliomalvis answer more applicable in my case. I can send data by serverSideProps. and catch it in pageProps. so I don't need to call the same API again with Component.fetchData.